# Excel 2010 VBA: LTrim function and IF block not resulting in expected result

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

Background: I import CSV data into Excel then have to find and replace certain accounts and replace them with other accounts (these are in a table) to prepare the file for upload to ERP System.

Problem: Original Account: `"     -   -000"`  (quotes added by me)
must be replaced with Account: `12345-123-000`

I have tried using :

1. VLOOKUP but that fails; VLOOKUP returns #N/A even though the lookup value is in the table
2. LTrim function to remove the leading spaces but LTrim does not trim the leading spaces
3. ASC to identify the ASC Code of the leading spaces; most are CHR(160) and some include CHR(32); I have done this to be sure the string are identical and they are
4. IF Block fails to resolve TRUE even when comparing variable values, as in the Watch window are identical.

Here is my procedure:

```
Sub ReplaceAcctOnJE()
    Dim intSRow As Integer 'in Imported CSV
    Dim intTRow As Integerin 'in Replacements Table
    Dim strVLValue As String 'Account in CSV
    Dim strVLUValue As String 'Account in Replacements Table

    intSRow = 1
    Do
        intSRow = intSRow + 1
        strVLValue = Cells(intSRow, "F")
        Cells(intSRow, "F").Select '***** TEMP *****
        intTRow = 6
        Do
            intTRow = intTRow + 1
            strVLUValue = Sheets("Tables").Cells(intTRow, "O")
            If strVLValue = strVLUValue Then
                strVLUValue = Sheets("Tables").Cells(intTRow, "P")
                Cells(intSRow, "F") = strVLUValue
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Tables").Cells(intTRow + 1, "O")) 
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(intSRow + 1, "F"))
End Sub
```

I am stumped by this behavior and do not understand why it is failing.
Is this a bug in Excel?

Comment: This is probably because you have trailing whitespace on one or both of the values you are comparing. Try, instead:

`If trim(strVLValue) = trim(strVLUValue) Then`

Comment: Can you show your worksheet?  This is probably possible without VBA but I need to see data.

Comment: None of the `Trim` functions work with `chr(160)` - you should use `Replace` instead.

Comment: JNevill, when I pause over the two variables being compared, the VBE displays their values and I have verified that they are identical.

Comment: chancea, this needs to be automated because there can be numerious entries in a data set of some 18000 records.

Comment: Rory, I will consider the Excel `Replace()` function. Curious how you learned that `Trim`  will not work with `Chr(160)`?

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA, this formula just checks if the first character from left is a **space** in original broken table (in my case "A2").
If true, take the value from other table (in my case the "F2"), if not, keep the original value.

```
=IF(LEFT(A2;1)=CHAR(32);F2;A2)
```

There can be more conditions to check, but from your example, this does the trick.

[image]